# How to Do Auto Click Displaying ng-repeat value in Welcome Page Section Using Ionic 2 Dynamically?

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic2

How to do auto `on click` in  displaying ng-repeat first value in welcome page section using Ionic 2 Dynamically?

- I'm developing application in Ionic 2.
- If i am sign in to the application  it's direct in to the welcome page, in this welcome page there are some ng-repeat values are displaying , if we click any of one value it's redirect into the authenticate value page...
- What i'm exactly looking is, if i sign in to the application it's direct to the welcome page, but while i'm entering to the welcome page the first ng-repeat value should click automatically and it's redirect to authenticate value page...
- first step is i'm sign in to the application then it's redirect to welcome page, after that the displaying ng-repeat first value  should click automatically and needs to redirect that value page...
- How to do auto click in first ng-repeat value in ionic 2? while entering into the welcome page...
- for example look this [Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/SJ8GtqbRntby5yGzLEft/) if we entered into this plunker first `tab1` page is displaying , then `open modal` button is available, if click that `open modal` button it's redirect to the authenticate page....but i am looking for while entering into `tab1` page the `open modal` button should click automatically (or) should need to redirect modal page....auto `on click` functionality needs to do this process, i have tried but unable to get the solution.....
- As of now while sign in to the application i'm direct to the welcome page, then some ng-repeat value is displaying in this welcome page, and while clicking first ng-repeat value it's redirect to authenticate page, but i'm looking for auto click first value like kind of autosubmit method...
- For example :- while entering to the home page , the first ng-repeat value need to click automatically (or) needs to redirect first ng-repeat values page....
- Is there any auto click functionality is available, i'm looking for auto click value functionalities,
- If have any examples and solution please suggest and update thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Since i don't know your code here is what you can do:

You can use Ionic 2 or Angular 2 page lifecycle events to fire something when the page is loading/loaded. Check out the [NavController LifeCycle Docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/#nav-controller) if you need further advise.

Since a click is just a way to call a function there's other ways to do this, for example, on javascript we use `document.ready()` function to do something when the page is loaded. In Ionic 2/Angular 2 we can do this as well.

You'll not simulate a click, you'll just call a function.

But lets do some coding. You can add this to your home .ts file:

```
// AGAIN: since i don't know your code, i'll do something on my own.
import { ModalController } from 'ionic-angular';

export class HomePage {
  myNgrepeatData: any[] = [];
  constructor(public modCtrl: ModalController){}

  ionViewWillLoad(){
    // in this first lifeCycle you'll load all the data you need, this function fires when you'll load the page
    // Here you'll get the data you'll display on the ngRepeat (on ionic 2 it's ngFor).
    this.myNgrepeatData = SomethingToGetData();
  }

  ionViewDidLoad(){
    // In this function - called when the view is finally loaded, you'll call your modal AND pass your first object property as an parameter.

    // You'll declare a modal and pass these arguments:
    // 1 - The page you want to show.
    // 2 - Your object, or the first property first value, since you know you want this.
    // 3 - Optional values for configuring your modal.
    const modal = this.modalCtrl.create(ThePageToRedirect, this.myNgrepeatData[0], { enableBackdropDismiss: false });

    // this is also opitional, if you want to do something when the modal is dismissed.
    modal.onDidDismiss(data => {
        // DO STUFF
    });

    // present it if not signed in
    var signed: boolean;
    signed = DoSignCodeYouNeedToDo();
    if(signed){
      // DO WHAT YOU WANT IF ALREADY SIGNED IN
    } else {
      modal.present();
    }

    // IF YOU NEED TO REDIRECT TO A PAGE USE NAVCONTROLLER LIKE THIS:
    // this.navCtrl.push(PageYouWant, this.myNgrepeatData[0]);
  }
}
```

As you may know, on your modal you'll need to import the `ViewController` from `ionic-angular` to dismiss the page.

If you need more assistance just ask. Hope this helps you :)

Comment: And you can algo use promises, it could make your code shorter. If you want to know more about it just ask and i'll edit my answer

Comment: Here we have updated [ionic 1 plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/ikUeQS37R5wUXHY76KPE/), when we open this plunker the `tab-friends.html` page is displaying and there are ng-repeat values are list out in `tab-friends.html` page, if we click ng-repeat value it’s redirect to that authenticate page. but we looking for when we open the plunker  the first ng-repeat value like `Scruff McGruff` needs to click automattically (or) redirect to that value authenticate page… like auto click function please check and update thanks…. but we exactly looking this solution in `ionic 2`,...

Comment: above we have updated `ionic 1 plunker` if possible can you suggest how to do this in `ionic 2` we looking for  auto click first ne-repeat value....thank you so much for your help and above answer....

Comment: This is what i1m doing in my answer, i've updated to use push to another page intead of a modal, but this is exactly what i'm doing in my code. I'm redirecting the first value of the repeat to a page. Could you at least try it?

Comment: yeah thank you so much, if possible can you update my plunker as well to know exact solution....thanks....i will do try your code as well.......

Comment: I'm sorry but your plunkr is ionic 1 and i don't know how to do this in ionic 1.